# Unable to compile Google SignIn SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to integrate Google SignIn sdk in my swift app. Here is the code.

```
    var configureError: NSError?
    GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
    assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

I am getting the following error.

[image]

Comment: try adding .a file to embedded libraries in general

Comment: I am using pod link provided by google.

Comment: are you getting any warning while installing pods?

Comment: here is the link @techloverr https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating#set_up_your_cocoapods_dependencies

Comment: any warnings? or suggestions

Comment: No warnings or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced these stuff & I simply solved it by removing following line from my AppDelegate and add this line into my ViewController.swift:

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self